# Regex: Match everything except strings ending in a control group

Tags: regex

I'm scraping some websites and I would like to discard the calls made to common img files based on a regex. The regex function should be

**Match everything except URLs (string) ending in .jpg, .png, .gif**

Examples:

- www.example.com/test.jpg
- www.example.com/test2.png

I ‘ve  tried doing this

```
.*(?:(?!\.(jpg|png|gif)))$
```

But without any success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct negative look ahead you are trying to construct is this,

```
(?!.*\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$)
```

Which will reject a string if it ends with either `jpg` or `png` or `gif` and the overall regex you need to use to reject strings is this,

```
^(?!.*\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$).+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fx9OyR/1)**

Also, the problem with your regex `.*(?:(?!\.(jpg|png|gif)))$` is, `.*` will already consume everything greedily leaving no characters further ahead, and hence your negative lookahead will always satisfy as true, as there won't be any characters left after that on whose basic the negative look ahead can reject your string. Hence, you need to move `.*` inside the negative look ahead to check for allowance of zero or more any other characters before `.jpg` or `.png` or `.gif`